# How can a SurfaceView be put into a layered hierarchy of Views?

Tags: android, surfaceview, layer

I want to create a hierarchy of `View`s in layers one on top of the other that is, roughly:

FrameLayout {
  SurfaceView
  View
  View
  SurfaceView
  View
  SurfaceView
}

I want each `SurfaceView`'s draw events to appear in the correct position in the hierarchy.  For example, the top surface should appear in front of everything.  The bottom one should appear behind everything.

Unfortunately, I can make each surface appear in front of everything using `setZOrderOnTop(true)` and I can make each surface appear at the bottom by NOT doing this, but I can't make one appear in the middle.  How would one do this?

Comment: You do not have to use FrameLayout, you can use addContentView() in onCreate. I doubt that Android will perform well with so many views. All can be done with one or two views.

Comment: I have a series of buttons off to one side so in fact I can't use the activity's root `FrameLayout`, but since it IS a `FrameLayout` this just begs the question.  My application absolutely requires that I produce a layered graphic with rapidly changing elements between relatively static ones, so I must either implement complex custom drawing in a `View` or use layers (ultimately the custom drawing will end up doing the same processing).

Comment: Since only one view can take touch input and the user can see only one surface, then everything depends on the hierachy of drawing. A single custom view with canvas could do the job. Though sometimes below normal android views, one places a custom view for an animated background. So I cannot see how can any application require more than two real layers... I am curious what are you trying to make...

Comment: I'm receiving touch events from the `FrameLayout` and passing them down to the surfaces as required; the application basically draws in three layers, and I am using the `SurfaceView`s to deal with active drawing (which needs rapid update) and the other `View`s to deal with already-drawn elements (as soon as they stop being changed they are moved from the `SurfaceView` to the `View`).  Rather than redraw everything each time OR use intermediate `Bitmap`s (I'm sure you know about the memory issues) I have this hierarchy.

Comment: Yes that is one soulution. You just need to check frame rate and see how it performs. I think that another view takes another screen memory buffer for its canvas. I know how difficult is to handle memory as I have an app Kaleido-Magic on the market which is using big images...

Comment: Well with one `SurfaceView` it's been working brilliantly, but putting in the others (supposed to be located between the other `View`s as mentioned) seems impossible: they're either fully at the back or fully at the front.

Comment: I would not try to do that because I don't think that Android is designed for many SurvaceViews overlaping transparently and it may work on some device and not another. But you can experiment and see... good luck!

Comment: Well, I can make all three `SurfaceView`s operate correctly in the sense that they animate how I want them to, but I can't get them into a layered hierarchy.  So until someone tells me how it's done I think I am going to answer this question myself with "this is impossible".

Comment: I've just implemented a drawing class which draws a path and blits two `Bitmap`s on to a SurfaceView in order to allow the path to be drawn between the `Bitmap`s.  It is MUCH SLOWER than the hierarchy of views I had before, though it does allow drawings to be animated on any layer.  I am, therefore, disappointed.

Answer (score 0):

`FrameLayout` is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. Generally, `FrameLayout` should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other.

I suggest you use a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` instead.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood: I want all the layers to overlap.  In fact I want them to be literally occupying different layers of the same rectangle; moreover this is working very well, except that `SurfaceView` elements are either right at the back or right at the front (and I want one of them in the middle).

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, this appears to be impossible.

Comment: Have you tried getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT) for the top SurfaceViews ? I am just doing a camera overlay...

Comment: Getting it to overlay is not the problem—the problem is getting the non-transparent pixels to display *underneath* the top elements, but *above* the bottom ones.